# Change html image every tick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, image

I am trying to check for the content of a html form every 10ms with JavaScript, and if the contents of the form are equal to a certain string, it will change the html image. This is my code:

```
<form>
  Search<br/>
  <input type="text" name="search"/>
</form>

<img id="image" src="images/image.png"/>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function searchtoJS {
    var userSearch = document.getElementsByName("search")[0].value;
}

setInterval(searchtoJS(), 10);

if (userSearch.toLowerCase() == "test" || "test2" || "1") {
    document.getElementById("image").src="images/image2.png";
}
</script>
```

Like I said, I just started with JavaScript, so bear with me with this code.

I will be very grateful for any help :)

Comment: What if your images take longer than 10ms to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you nearly got it:

all you need to do is to move your check inside of the function that is triggered every x ms like so:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 Search<br>
    <input type="text" name="search"/>
</form>

<br><br>

<img id="image" src="images/1.jpg"/>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
function searchtoJS () {
    var userSearch = document.getElementsByName("search")[0].value;
    if (userSearch.toLowerCase() === "test" || userSearch.toLowerCase() ===  "test2" || userSearch.toLowerCase() === "1") {
        document.getElementById("image").src="images/2.jpg"; 
    }
}

setInterval(searchtoJS, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

post this in a file test.html create a folder images and then put 2 images one called 1.jpg and the other 2.jpg.

Comment: I fixed the setInterval issue, yet it doesnt seem to work. Im guessing that the code doesnt properly check the content of the html form and convert it to a JS variable, because I cant find any issue with the JS code... Tho Im pretty sure you can check the content of a html text input without having to submit it in any way....

Comment: oh i just have seen that you used == to compare the string instead of === . does this fixes it? btw, open your site in chrome and press f12 so you can just debug it

Comment: No, that unfortunetaly doesnt fix it. But there shouldnt be any problem with checking the content of a text form without having to submit it using javascript, should there?

Comment: No you dont have to have to post it to the server. i will set the file up locally and edit my anser in a sec...

Comment: Sometimes the easy things can get complicated too :D the expression with || within strings in javascripts means that if the first expression is undefined take the one provided on the right side, as the string "test" is never undefined it would only work if the user writes test in the input. the edit now should work in all cases

Comment: I used exactly the same code as your edit, yet it still doesnt seem to work... I cant think of what it could be

Comment: Follow the instructions from this edit :) if this dont works i will quit my job now :D :D

Comment: Perhaps if I elaborate a little bit on what Im trying to achieve, maybe you can think of another way of doing this. There are a number of images, and I want a "search" box for the user to type in. Whenever they type in something that corresponds to one of the images, it will highlight.

Answer (score 0):

The code wont work because of the brackets `()` you have inserted in the `setInterval()`.

`setInterval` needs a function as a parameter.
What your code does is, it executes the function and returns to the `setInterval` whatever is returned. In this case nothing is returned. So your code wont work.

It should be something as follows:

```js
var i = 0;

function changeContent() {
  document.getElementById("oneDiv").innerHTML = i++;
}

setInterval(changeContent, 100);
```

```html
<div id="oneDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to the use of jQuery, you could do away with executing that function every 10ms and instead, run a function whenever the input changes.

You would need to give the input an id like the example.

```
<input id="searchField" type="text" name="search">

$('#searchField').on('input', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "test") {
        document.getElementById("image").src="images/image2.png";
    }
});
```